# How can i identify a turtle from a list by its position in Python?

Tags: python

I'm coding a race of multiple turtles, and I would like to access my list of turtles and atm when I print the winner I get " turtle.Turtle object at 0x05D8A770". I would like to get the actual colour of the winning turtle from my list.

Thank you,
Suz

Comment: Suz, please post all code which is relevant to the problem directly in your question body. Also, it would be easier for users to help you if you added a [mcve].

Comment: please post your code as a code block not as an image

Comment: Dear suz , please post your code as it is for help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
print(winningturtle.pencolor())
```

or:

```
print(winningturtle.fillcolor())
```

depending on which one you want. For more info on turtle, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html)

Comment: When a question solves your problem, you can click the green tick. It lets others know that it is a working solution, and gives the answerer 15 reputation.